# iOS5 + jquery-mobile transition blinks

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to remove an annoying flickering effect on jqmobile transitions when running on iOS 5. I tried several methods from other posts like -webkit-backface and did some other work but does not reach complete solution. I observed that flickr occurs when, before transition, page is repositioned due to navigation bar is displaced one pixel (maybe 2) from top. Problem begins on initialization or after device rotation when page is rerendered and then we got two possible working results,

1. Working without flickering and expected on each transition.
2. Falls on each transition appearing described blink.

problem, of course, is that you get 1 or 2 randomly when new page render. Thank you.

Comment: Did you see [this website](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024)?

Comment: tried some of described methods but no luck but looks promising. Keep trying...

Comment: @gtm, please post it as an answer, was starting point to get it running! thanks

Comment: Posted it, glad I could help...

Comment: Sorry, my answer was deleted by a moderator because I just provided the link. Which solution in the thread worked for you?

Comment: was a combination of them. Mainly data-position, webkit backface and others not provide a full solution and I set a custom css from jqmobile 1.0 posted on a github link from suggested by you and finally works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of the methods [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024) should do the trick...

For others who have this problem, the OP said that

> Mainly data-position, webkit backface and others not provide a full solution and I set a custom css from jqmobile 1.0 posted on a github link from suggested by you and finally works

Answer (score 7):

If you have `data-position="fixed"` then a solution is to use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: This worked to get rid of flicker in between pages... and it reduced the time that the URL bar pops down and back up.  It's not all the way gone yet, though.

Comment: BTW, the "cause" of my flicker after this fix is because my fixed header toolbar is 2 rows (instead of the usual 1 row).  Any good ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: This works! It fixed the problem with minimal effort. (jQM 1.3.1, Cordova 2.4.0)

Answer (score 4):

*Source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024#issuecomment-5124172*

> Instead of data-position:fixed to the header / footer - I applied the
>   following CSS styles to the header, content and footer:

```
.header {
    position : fixed;
    z-index  : 10;
    top      : 0;
    width    : 100%
}
.content {
    padding : 45px 15px
}
.footer {
    position : fixed;
    z-index  : 10;
    bottom   : 0;
    width    : 100%
}
```

Several people on the forum at the above link have stated that this has helped with flashes when transition between pages with `data-position:fixed` header/footer.

Another suggestion from Tod Parker (a jQuery Mobile creator) was this:

```
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-header-fixed,
.ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning .ui-footer-fixed { visibility: hidden; }
```

Which hides the fixed header/footer while transitioning from one page to another.

*Source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024#issuecomment-5250856*

There was also a commit made by another jQuery Mobile team member that should show-up in the next release. Here is the post: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024#issuecomment-5250856 (the code is a bit complex to post here)

Very recently the issue was closed due to this commit: https://github.com/Diveboard/jquery-mobile/commit/ff125b65e682ecd33888a6db1221ac441d258994. This fix was to set the `z-index` of the incoming page to `-10` before scrolling and then resetting the `z-index` afterwards.

I haven't attempted any of these fixes myself but they seem to be promising.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add data-transition as specified here: [Display issues when we change from one jquery mobile page to another in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868493/display-issues-when-we-change-from-one-jquery-mobile-page-to-another-in-firefox)

Here is the example from the answer above:

```
<a href="#page1" data-transition="fade">I am good transition</a>
<a href="#page1">And I am bad</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got flicker and blinking when a slide in panel was installed. The blinking funnily enough happens even when the panel is hidden, and for me occurred on collapsible elements.

My 'solution' was to add this to my css file: (as suggested from http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/ )  With JQuery Mobile 1.3.1 :

```
div {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
```

Which sounds crazy - but 'worked for me'. (Yes all divs)

Seems that there are no side effects seen - yet.

I have written programs in OpenGL, but don't have a clue what -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); would do.

Answer (score 0):

Common problems on Android 4.0+ as far as I discovered using Cordova 2.9. and JQM 1.3:
- page transition white flicker even when "none" transition specified
- double taps needed to do a navigation

Tested on SGII, Motorola MC40, TC55, same problems on all platforms.

Use custom style for header, footer, content, remove data-position="fixed"

Use initialization of JQM (be aware, place the JS **before** JQM include)

```
.header {
    position : fixed !important;
    z-index  : 10 !important;
    top      : 0 !important;
    width    : 100% !important;
}
.content {
    padding : 55px 15px !important;
}
.footer {
    position : fixed !important;
    z-index  : 10 !important;
    bottom   : 0 !important;
    width    : 100% !important;
}

//use this init

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
{
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "fade"; //default, see styles
    $.mobile.transitionFallbacks='none';
    $.mobile.useFastClick = false; //300ms or double tap needed
});
```