# white flickering when navigating in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've noticed a white flicker that appears when ever I navigate between any html files in my project except for when I navigate away from my index file. I'm using JQM but I'm not using ajax because I'm linking to multipage documents.

I've read this happening to people who use JQM along with Phonegap when making apps but for a regular desktop site, I am confused as to why this is happening. Any idea?

Comment: what version of jQMobile are you using?

Comment: I'm using Jquery Mobile 1.3

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

Remove `data-position="fixed"` on headers and footers if you are using it.

Then, apply the following CSS styles to your header, content and footer:

```
.header {
    position : fixed;
    z-index  : 10;
    top      : 0;
    width    : 100%
}
.content {
    padding : 45px 15px
}
.footer {
    position : fixed;
    z-index  : 10;
    bottom   : 0;
    width    : 100%
}
```

This idea/snippet is borrowed from what Jasper's answer (not the OP's accepted answer) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903433/ios5-jquery-mobile-transition-blinks). I was experiencing that flicker problem on a single-page jQuery Mobile v1.1.0 + Phonegap application and this solved it for me. Perhaps this same workaround will work for your multi-page application on v1.3.

Comment: This helped me on PhoneGap + 1.3JQM.
All page content have to be wrapped into content DIV.
For sure use !important attribute.